# How encrypt/decrypt AES 128, cypher mode ECB in Apex (Salesforce)?

Tags: security, encryption, cryptography, salesforce, apex

I need to encrypt and decrypt in AES 128, cypher mode ECB in Apex to work with an API
I try to use Crypto Class but cypher mode ECB is consider insecure for Salesforce so they don´t support this type of cypher mode.
There is a workaround?

Comment: Use CBC with an IV of all zeros on a plaintext of exactly 16 bytes and take the first 16 bytes of the ciphertext - this will be the equivalent of ECB. To understand why, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_block_chaining_(CBC)

Comment: "cypher" is really becoming the old spelling; most people prefer "cipher" by now, and that's how it is generally found in API's and such.